# How can I prove this is an $R$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a ring, $r_1\ldots,r_n\in R$ and $P(r_1,\ldots,r_n)=\{(c_1,\ldots,c_n)\in R^n|\sum c_ir_i=1\}$.

I'm trying to prove that $P(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ is an $R$-module, how would be a good candidate to the operations $(+, \cdot)$ to turn $P(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ in an $R$-module? I'm struggling a lot to find a well-defined operation; any suggestions?

**EDIT**

For $n=2$ and $R$ a field we have for the operation $+$, $(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\in P(a_1,a_2)$, $(x_1,x_2)+(y_1,y_2)= (x_1+y_1-a_1^{-1},x_2+y_2)$, it seems well-defined, but how can we generalize to any ring? it's more difficult than I thought.

Comment: There is no natural $R$-module structure here, some context on *why* you want this to be an $R$-module would help.

Comment: Anon's (+1) suggestion of transport of structure should work. PROVIDED that the set $P(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n)$ is not empty. After all we could have something like: $R=\Bbb{Z}$, $r_i$ all even.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen But $R$ is any ring

Comment: Ok. If $R$ has a non-trivial ideal $I$, what happens, if $r_i\in I$ for all $i$? The set $P(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n)$ will be empty!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen so you meant that there should be at least one $r_i$ unit?

Comment: No, Jyrki is saying my answer works provided $P(r_1,\cdots,r_n)$ is nonempty, which is equivalent to there being at least one solution, which is equivalent to $(r_1,\dots,r_n)=R$ as ideals.

Comment: I guess we need $(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n)=R$ as a **left** ideal, if $R$ is not commutative.

Answer (score 1):

Take some inspiration from linear algebra. If $R$ were a field then $A=P(r_1,\cdots,r_n)$ would be some affine subspace $-$ a translate, or coset, of the vector subspace $U$ comprised of points orthogonal to the vector $(r_1,\cdots,r_n)$. Forming a vector operation on this affine subspace would come down to choosing an origin $a\in A$: once you do that, you can use the idea of [transport of structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_of_structure) to say that $A\to U:x\mapsto x-a$ is a vector space isomorphism (this determines the operations on $A$).

Check that this works with arbitrary $R$-modules. The operation needs to be $R$-linear.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant, first we define an identity element, after we define the operations? I don't think $A$ would be some affine subspace comprised of points orthogonal to the vector $(r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ because the sum $\sum c_ir_i$ isn't equal to $0$

Comment: @user122342 Do you know the equations for a hyperplane $\Pi$? If $n$ is the normal vector and $p\in\Pi$ then the equation is $n\cdot(x-p)=0$, which can be normalized to $m\cdot x=1$, which is precisely the equation you have. And no, you define the origin of the affine subspace before you put a vector structure on it.

Comment: yes, so $A$ would be a hyperplane, am I right?

Comment: Yes $A$ would be a hyperplane, which is a type of affine subspace.

Comment: The vector $x,y\in A$ correspond to $x-a,y-a\in U$. Adding these vectors together in $U$ gives $x+y-2a\in U$, which corresponds back to $x+y-a$. Therefore $x+_Ay:=x+y-a$. I'll leave determining the scalar operation on $A$ up to you; use the same reasoning. Then generalize to arbitrary $R$-modules.

Comment: I'm beginning to understand what you mean, thanks!

Comment: For $n=2$ and $R$ a field we have for the operation $+$, $(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\in P(a_1,a_2)$, $(x_1,x_2)+(y_1,y_2)= (x_1+y_1-a_1^{-1},x_2+y_2)$, it seems well-defined, but how can we generalize to any ring? it's more difficult than I thought.